# Daily Life of Mr.X

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story, video-games

> 18 to 21: Search around internet like a blitz.
>
> 21 to 24: Exercise, both physically and mentally.
>
> 0 to 3: Direct and amplify a searchlight.
>
> 3 to 6: Forecast about cyclones twice.
>
> 6 to 9: Watch the sunrise.
>
> 9 to 12: Check his refrigerator.
>
> 12 to 15: Set mouse traps on the 1st floor.
>
> 15 to 18: Copy a horror movie.

What is the full name of Mr.X?

Subtle Hint:

> The list is cyclic, but it must be in order.

Moderate Hint:

> Mr.X has "no" partner.

Decisive Hint:

> Mr.X's name is literally "X".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full name of Mr. X is

> MegaMan X

The items in his daily routine represent

> The bosses in a MegaMan X videogame, or the weapons obtained by defeating them. Because the list is cyclic, the bosses must be ordered according to which boss is vulnerable to the weapon Mr. X obtains by defeating the previous boss. That boss prizes and vulnerabilities form a cyclic list is true for every MegaMan game in the main series.

But which...

> The "forecast about cyclones twice" is sufficient to single out MegaMan X4. The items in the schedule correspond to:
>  Lightning Web: Search around internet like a blitz.
>  Soul Body: Exercise, both physically and mentally.
>  Aiming Laser: Direct and amplify a searchlight.
>  Double Cyclone: Forecast about cyclones twice.
>  Rising Fire: Watch the sunrise.
>  Frost Tower: Check his refrigerator.
>  Ground Hunter: Set mouse traps on the 1st floor.
>  Twin Slasher: Copy a horror movie.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer maybe???

18-21:

> Google?

0-3:

> Laser?

12-15:

> Exterminate?

15-18:

> Pirate?

So:

> G _ L _ _ _ E P

Comment: Not quite. You should consider the "video games" tag.